# Django Rest Framework with AJAX

Tags: ajax, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have been learning the django rest framework and i have created a few api calls. I have also used the django rest framework TokenAuthentication to give each user in my database a token to authorise the call. I was just wondering what is the best way to pass the token into javascript? Do i have to pass the token to a django view? Or is there a way to pass the token into javascript directly?

As i am new to this I want to be learning the best practices, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the authentication token using ajax inside the headers.

```
$.ajax({ url: '/api/v1/get-users',
         type: 'get',
         headers: {'Authorization': 'Token <your token>'},
         success: (e) => {
                  console.log(e)
         },
         error: (e)=>{
                  console.log(e)
         }                
})
```

Comment: Thankyou fro your input. Maybe my question was a little confusing, but what i am wondering is how can i get the token into javascript eg as a variable, so i can then use this method afterwards?

Comment: well that depends how you're getting the token itself. so if you are sending the token in the context a simple way would be to save it as a variable inside the script tags. var `token = {{token}}` If you want to know how you can obtain the token through ajax thatsa different story